# Definition of "of odd order"

Tags: definition

Could someone point me to a definition of "odd order"? 
The definition of group order I found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupOrder.html) seems to refer to a group as a set of numbers. The context that I'm reading about 'odd order' is: "$p\ \alpha\ d_{eh_1}E(t)$; it is initially linear in $E(t)$ and thus of odd order with respect to the driving field sign".

Then later it mentions $d^2_{eh_1}E(t)^2$ as also being of odd order. Could someone clarify why this is the case?

Comment: Your bunches of symbols don't look like they denote groups to me.

Comment: From the tiny tidbit of text you've given, it doesn't appear to be talking about groups at all. Without more context, I can't interpret what it is saying, but "initially linear" would suggest it is talking about polynomial degree. I.e., when the driving field sign changes, so does the sign of the result.